# How does one achieve ternary assignment in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, variable-assignment, conditional-operator, assignment-operator

I would like to do a reassignment of a class variable in Javascript (or Typescript) using a ternary operator. The reassignment of `this.foo` depends on the current value of `this.foo` which I can update with the following:

```
setFoo = () => {
    this.foo = this.foo ? "" : "foo";
}
```

However, I am wondering if I can do reassignment of `this.foo` without writing `this.foo` twice. This would be helpful because I am trying to dynamically update classes on an Angular component (written in Typescript).

I would like to be able to write something like the following which makes use of truthy/falsy values. If `this.foo` is truthy, then `""` is assigned; otherwise, `"foo"` is assigned:

```
setFoo = () => {
    this.foo =? "" : "foo";
}
```

I have tried searching for similar questions but could not find an answer. My initial thought was to use the ??= operator in Typescript 4.0 but I do not think it will work. Perhaps my ideal solution does not exist because it could be a bad programming habit. Thanks

Comment: you should clarify what you are trying to do. you wrote, this.foo is falsy, then "", but the code you wrote does the opposite.

Comment: @Rick, I am trying to assign "" if this.foo if this.foo is truthy. That was a typo initially. Thanks for catching that. I have edited my question.

Comment: The only thing possible is `this.foo = this.foo || ""` and `this.foo = this.foo && ""`. That does not quite fit your need, but still is shorter.

Comment: ternary is the shortest one for two different values.

Comment: Why? Ternary itself is awful enough, though I nowadays find myself using it more often with `const`. Don't minify your developement code, let a minifier do that when you're releasing the code to production.

Comment: the way you have written it works and is concise enough. I don't see any reason to want to shorten it.

Comment: @Teemu and @Rick, I asked because writing `this.foo` twice is redundant and I was curious to know if I could eliminate that redundancy. Thank you for the responses; I agree the current way is concise.

Comment: I don't find two `this.x`s being redundant in that specific syntax, as there are two operators, and both of the operators need their operands. The case just happens to use the same variable in the operands of both of the operators. If the case was `const x = (y) ? 1 : 2;`, you wouldn't think `1` was redundant. For what you're after, we'd need a brand new "check&assign" operator ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question. **Unfortunately this is not possible**. There is a shorthand version that some people use, but it still includes a duplication:

```
foo = foo || otherCondition;
```

So the shorthand of a shorthand, not too useful in my opinion.

**Short answer**: I'd go with the normal ternary.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the IF ELSE instead of using ternary statement,
if else will give you more control on the statement written under it's and efficient to use.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but this doesn't solve my issue of writing `this.foo` twice. Once would be within the if statement condition and the other would be assigning the variable.